# What's up with Jase and his nametag?

Tags: discussion, trolling, user-accounts

Over the last 6 weeks or so, we've seen effectively the same question posted (at least) 5 times:

- [Use preferred name at work?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/136992/use-preferred-name-at-work)
- [Can you use a preferred name tag at work](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/136247/can-you-use-a-preferred-name-tag-at-work)
- [Name tag at work - using a nickname](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/134213/name-tag-at-work-using-a-nickname)
- [Preferred name at work](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/134118/preferred-name-at-work)
- [Is it fine to use your name tag as your nickname at a job](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/137743/is-it-fine-to-use-your-name-tag-as-your-nickname-at-a-job)

I probably didn't even find them all, I remember seeing others. Is this a troll? Someone confused about how the site works? Some sort of bot?

Comment: Yes, I've seen it at least 3 times now... the same post, really unclear, seems trollish by nature... really starting to think that user should be banned (if such thing exists) or at least earn a time in the penalty box... the thing is, it seems each time the user creates a new account: this one is 13 days old

Comment: Random idea: Leave one of those posts undeleted, so we can then swiftly close as dupe when the user posts the same thing again.

Comment: @DarkCygnus Can't close as dupe as it is unanswered

Comment: @bruglesco well, then, let's leave one Undeleted and with an answer saying "Yes it is fine, Jase", and use that as the target dupe?

Comment: moderators suspended [involved account](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/104508/jason-dilibero). With 10K+ reputation you can check if other deleted posts were written from the same account and if not, we can ask them to use additional measures explained by Stack Overflow moderator [at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328144/165773)

Answer (score 22):

A troll or someone who does not have a complete grasp of communication or social convention.

Even if trolling is not the intent, the result is indistinguishable.

I'm continually saddened that Jason Dilibero is not confident enough to call himself what he wants.

It's ok Jase, it's really ok.

Answer (score 12):

While I'm typically loathe to write users off as a troll unless the content is blatantly trollish I can't even come close to the contortions required to make a case for legitimacy here.

Essentially copy-pasting the same question over and over and over (and over), even though they have (repeatedly) received a plain answer to their question goes far beyond someone lacking social skills.  There is zero attempt to engage with the site and community just the same old groundhog day question.

So, I don't think this is a good faith user, even if I can can't for the life of me work out what the motivation is!

As something of an FYI he's posted it [again](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/137743/is-it-fine-to-use-your-name-tag-as-your-nickname-at-a-job) (deleted question so 10k required to view). Tip of the hat to Snow for deleting the latest Groundhog day loop.

Comment: Can users see their own deleted content? I've been wondering: Is it possible that he comes back, looks for his old question, doesn't see it (because it's been deleted) and re-creates it?

Comment: @dwizum I'm not sure on whether you can see your own deleted stuff to be honest. If you can't then I suppose what you describe is *possible* but I have to say it still doesn't seem all that *plausible* to me.

Comment: Just spitballing to eliminate possibilities. After all, once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth!

Comment: @dwizum Conan Doyle reference.. nicely done!

Comment: @dwizum you can see your own deleted content but it isn't easy and intuitive. You have to go to the deleted content page via a link that is easy to miss. I personally had to look it up on Meta.SE before I knew how to get to it.